# iOS, Android, Blackberry etc, which of the mobile OS is the most hacker-friendly?

Tags: android, ios, iphone, security, blackberry

I'm a developer and ***I have the desire to do everything technically possible*** with my mobile device, such as programmatically placing calls, programmatically deciding whether what to do with an incoming call (hang up, divert to voicemail, play an automated message etc), programmatically sending text messages, accepting push notifications from my own servers, allowing me to read data from the GPS device, periodically taking pictures, running my own programs without making them to the app store, etc...

Which of the existing mobile device platforms has the most liberal and feature-complete API that may allow some of the above? Good documentation would be a plus :=)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you feel hackish in anyway and your only purpose is to taylor YOUR phone the way you want without feeling the need to make your hack-thingie available into an appstore...then the answer is easy :

Android.

The documentation is poor, badly written, the apis are full of little annoying bugs and all that BUT : Whatever you don't find in the official API's you can hack by forking your own Android.

For example none of the mobile frameworks allow developers to send audio to a caller during a call. I personally cannot see the reason but you just can't. Fork your Android, add the missing bits and off you go.

Comment: Can I load my own version of Android on an Android phone/tablet? If that depends on the particular model, do most devices out there allow that? Are the compiler tools generally available?

Comment: Most Android phones are closed and you can only upgrade using a signed binary, but the Google Nexus (the first one) is open in any way. No problem with compiling your own Kernel and uploading it to the device.

Comment: @JustSid: Thanks. What about tablets?

Comment: actually, rooting any android device allows you to put your own ROM (self built android) onto it. That's why most people do it.

Comment: Android is open and as far as i understood the TOS rooting an Android phone or tablet is legal and should not void your warranty...at least in the US. see : http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Google%20Mobile/thread?tid=19e05c1159ef7f77&hl=en .  You can also root any tablet provided you find the right toos : see galaxytab : http://www.addictivetips.com/hardware/how-to-root-samsung-galaxy-tab-with-superoneclick-rooting-app/

Comment: Thanks everyone. It's unfortunate that the question has to be closed.